# need to make a web page which sends push notifications to my android phonegap hybrid app

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-pushplugin

I am new to this.

I need to make a web page (which i plan on making using node.js) to send a push notification to hybrid app (which i plan on making using phonegap)

Any hints or tutorials would be lovely. Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Pushbots and Cordova. Follow this link:
http://thejackalofjavascript.com/pushbots-and-cordova/

Comment: thanks - very helpful. but it the dashboard says 0 devices eventhough my app is running on the phone and ive cross checked the pushbot app id and gcm project no